# Aggregate Map of map values using Spark DataSet

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

I have the columnfamily in cassandra in the following map format which I want to process using Spark DataSet. So, I want to bucket the models values in two categories premium (`City and Duster`) vs non-premium (`Alto K10, Aspire, Nano and i10`) and I want the final count of values of premium vs non-premium which would be 2 (`City` and `Duster` count) vs 10 (`Alto K10, Aspire, Nano and i10`).

**Code :**

```
  case class UserProfile(userdata:Map[String,Map[String,Int]])

 val userprofileDataSet = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map("table"->"userprofilesagg","keyspace" -> "KEYSPACENAME")).load().as[UserProfile]
```

How do to the processing on userprofileDataSet ??

**Data Format:**

```
 {'bodystyle': {'Compact Sedan': 1, 'Hatchback': 8, 'SUV': 1, 'Sedan': 4},   
    'models': {'Alto K10': 3, 'Aspire': 4, 'City': 1, 'Duster': 1, 'Nano': 3, 'i10': 2}}
```

**Edited question:**

With respect to squid's answer. I want to aggregate the results for each user now like this :

```
    DOICvncGKUH9xBLnW3e9jXcd2 | non-premium | [Nano, Alto K10, Aspire, i10] | 12 | premium | [City, Duster] | 2
    BkkpgeAdCkYJEXsdZjiVz3bSb | non-premium | [Nano, Alto K10, Aspire, i10] | 17 | premium | [City, Duster] | 5
```

Now case class would look like this

**Case class:**

```
 case class UserProfile(userid:String, userdata:Map[String,Map[String,Int]])
```

**Data:**

```
DOICvncGKUH9xBLnW3e9jXcd2 | {'bodystyle': {'Compact Sedan': 1, 'Hatchback': 8, 'SUV': 1, 'Sedan': 4},   
    'models': {'Alto K10': 3, 'Aspire': 4, 'City': 1, 'Duster': 1, 'Nano': 3, 'i10': 2}}

BkkpgeAdCkYJEXsdZjiVz3bSb | {'bodystyle': {'Compact Sedan': 7, 'Hatchback': 5, 'SUV': 3, 'Sedan': 7},   
    'models': {'Alto K10': 1, 'Aspire': 7, 'City': 4, 'Duster': 1, 'Nano': 8, 'i10': 1}}
```

Moreover, you asked regarding why I have mentioned Bodystyle. So that I could apply the similar aggregation `(SUV, Sedan)` as premium and rest non-premium on it.

Comment: do you want to process only models? what's role of bodystyle?

Comment: @squid I have edited the question. Could you please look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly is the role of `bodystyle`. If I understood the problem correctly then you want category and count, you may try something like below and remove `types` if not useful:

```
--userprofile table
CREATE TABLE `userprofile`(
`properties` map<string,map<string,int>>);

--Aggregate by category
select category, 
       collect_set(type) as types, 
       sum(value) as count 
from (select case when lower(type) in ('city','duster') then 'premium'
             when lower(type) in ('alto k10', 'aspire', 'nano' , 'i10') then 'non-premium'
        end as category,
        type,value 
 from (select properties['models'] as models from userprofile) t
    lateral view explode(models) t as type, value)l group by category
```

**Output**

```
category    |   types                            |         count
non-premium | ["Aspire","i10","Nano","Alto K10"] |         12
premium     | ["City","Duster"]                  |         2
```